# How we run magento cron.php in local machine?

Tags: php, magento

Let me know anyone have good idea about run the local magento cron.php for all history at once
.I ran the cron like localhost/test2/cron.php . but it takes  10 records at once. anyone know run for all stock updates at once?

Comment: You should not run cron.php but cron.sh which will do a call to the cron.php file.

Comment: I'm using windows platform machine. so i think i should run cron.php. cron.sh run in linux.

Comment: Have you found any solution sanji??